# What is the difference between strcmp() and strcoll()?

Tags: c++, c, string, locale

I tried understanding both of them but I did not find any differences except for `strcoll()` [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcoll) reference says that it

> compares two null terminated strings according to current locale as defined by the LC_COLLATE category.

On the second thoughts and I know I am asking another question for detailed answer, what exactly is this locale, for both C and C++?

Comment: The [example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcoll) seems pretty clear in my opinion.

Comment: @Rapptz...Oops...should have seen that link....before posting...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`strcmp()` takes the bytes of the string one by one and compare them as is whatever the bytes are.

`strcoll()` takes the bytes, transform them using the locale, then compares the result. The transformation re-orders depending on the language. In French, accentuated letters come after the non-accentuated ones. So **é** is after **e**. However, **é** is before **f**. `strcoll()` gets it right. `strcmp()` not so well.

However, in many cases `strcmp()` is enough because you don't need to show the result ordered in the language (locale) in use. For example, if you just need to quickly access a large number of data indexed by a string you'd use a map indexed by that string. It probably is totally useless to sort those using `strcoll()` which is generally very slow (in comparison to `strcmp()` at least.)

For details about characters you may also want to check out the [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) website.

In regard to the locale, it's the language. By default it is set to "C" (more or less, no locale). Once you select a location the locale is set accordingly. You can also set the LC_LOCALE environment variable. There are actually many such variables. But in general you use predefined functions that automatically take those variables in account and do the right thing for you. (i.e. format dates / time, format numbers / measures, compute upper / lower case, etc.)

Comment: +1 The samples of character comparison in this answer are very nicely presented, particularly the "However, é is before f." example. Likewise, the notes about using `strcmp()` for internal sort management vs display are equally well done. There are some answers that are succinct and speak volumes, and I wish I could up-vote them more than once. This is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason in all unicode locales I tested, on several different versions of glibc, strcoll() returns zero for any two hiraganas. This breaks **sort**, **uniq**, and everything that interacts with orders of strings in some way.

> $ echo -e -n 'い\nろ\nは\nに\nほ\nへ\nと\n' | sort | uniq
>
> い

which is simply broken beyond repair. People from different places of world might have different ideas on whether 'い' should be placed before or after 'ろ', but nobody sane would consider them the same.

And no, setting your locale to the Japanese one does not matter:

> $ LC_ALL=ja_JP.utf8 LANG=ja_JP.utf8 LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.utf8 echo -e -n 'い\nろ\nは\nに\nほ\nへ\nと\n' | sort | uniq
>
> い

There was discussion in some official mailing list, but guess what, it was in 2002 and it was never fixed because people don't care: https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-utf8@nl.linux.org/msg02658.html

That bug happened to us in some day and in the end our only way out was to set the collate locale to "C" and rely on the nice properties of utf-8 encoding. That's a horrible experience, since one shouldn't really work under "C" locale when processing all-Japanese data.

So for your sanity's sake, do NOT directly use strcoll. A safer variant might be:

```
int safe_strcoll(const char *a, const char *b)
{
  int ret = strcoll(a, b);
  if (ret != 0) return ret;
  return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

just in case strcoll() decides to screw you...

EDIT: I just repeated the experiment out of curiosity, and my current system (with glibc 2.29) works without problems now. Locale doesn't matter either.

Comment: I was lucky enough to spot the problem. Your change of environment only applies to `echo`. You should apply the change of language to `sort` and to `uniq` as well; the simplest is just to `export LANG`. It works perfectly with: `(export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8; echo -e -n 'い\nろ\nは\nに\nほ\nへ\nと\n' | sort | uniq)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Except I was actually using export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 when first doing this experiment. I tried again on multiple machines and can still reproduce the problem in some, but not all, of them.

I guess I need to dig a bit further as what caused the difference. glibc version seems not the only variable I need to control...