# C quick sort character array into alphabetical order

Tags: c, quicksort

I am fairly new to C and doing this as an exercise. The code compiles and runs before hitting a runtime error Abort trap: 6. I have tracked the bug to the counter `j` on the second call to the second recursive call meeting `i < last_line` going out of bounds. I cannot see the error in the code. Quick sort is not a method I am particularly familiar with; can anyone help me find the error?

The list of names I am feeding in is:

```
James
Janet
James
Rosie
Dave
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void quicksort(char **array, int first_line, int last_line) ;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0 ;
    int j = 0 ;
    int line_count = 0 ;
    int line_number = 20 ;
    char *lines[20] ;
    //char temp[BUFSIZ] ;
    FILE *foutptr ;
    FILE *finptr ;

    finptr = fopen("names.txt", "r") ;
    if(finptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: input file pointer") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    foutptr = fopen("sorted.txt", "w") ;
    if(foutptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: output file pointer") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    lines[i] = malloc(BUFSIZ) ;
    while(fgets(lines[i],BUFSIZ,finptr) && i < line_number)
    {
        printf("Element %d is the name %s.\n", i, lines[i]) ;
        i++ ;
        lines[i] = malloc(BUFSIZ) ;
    }

    printf("TEST %s.\n", *(lines+1)) ;
    line_count = i ;
    i = 0 ;
    char **all_lines = lines ; 

    quicksort(all_lines, 0, line_count-1) ;

    for(j = 0 ; j < line_count ; j++)
    {
        fprintf(foutptr, "%s", lines[j]) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}

void quicksort(char **array, int first_line, int last_line)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, x = 0, pivot = (first_line + last_line)/2 ;
    char temp[100] ;

    i = first_line ;
    j = last_line ;

    if(last_line - first_line < 1)
    {
        return ;
    } 

    printf("first_line = %d so i = %d. last line = %d so  j = %d. The pivot is %d \n", first_line, i, last_line, j, pivot) ;

    while(i <= j)
    {
        /* While array[i] proceeds the pivot alphabetically and is less than array[j] move through the array. This deals with first mismatching letter of first string is less than the second
   in ASCII character numbers i.e. if earlier in the alphabet as ASCII chartcters earlier in the alphabet have a lower numerical id */    
        while(strcmp(array[i], array[pivot]) < 0 && i < last_line)
        {
            printf("No swapping In while 1, comparing %s and %s with strcmp = %d. \n", array[i], array[pivot], strcmp(array[i], array[pivot])) ;
            printf("%d. \n", i) ;
            i++ ;
        }

        /* While array[j] follows the pivot alphabetically and is greater than array[i] move through the array. This deals with the first mismatching letter of first string compared to the second                    is greater in number id i.e. the ASCII character code is bigger in the first so it is  latter in the alphabet */
        while(strcmp(array[j], array[pivot]) > 0 && j > first_line)
        {
            printf("No swapping In while 2, comparing %s and %s with strcmp = %d. \n", array[j], array[pivot], strcmp(array[j], array[pivot])) ;
            printf("%d. \n", j) ;
            j-- ;
        }

                // Swap if the conditions above are not met 
        if(i <= j)
        {
            printf("%s\n","SWAPPING") ;
            printf("Array[%d] = %s, Array[%d] = %s", i, array[i], j,  array[j]) ;
            strcpy(temp,array[i]) ;
            strcpy(array[i], array[j]) ; 
            strcpy(array[j],temp) ;
            printf("Array[%d] = %s, Array[%d] = %s", i, array[i], j,  array[j]) ;           
            i++ ;
            j-- ;
        }
    }

    if(first_line < j)
    {
        printf("Recursive call 1: Lower bound = %d, Upper bound = %d\n", first_line, j) ;
        for(x = 0 ; x < last_line + 1 ; x++)
        {
            printf("Array[%d]: %s \n", x, array[x]) ;
        }
        quicksort(array, first_line, j) ;
    }

    x = 0 ;

    if(i < last_line)
    {
        printf("Recursive call 2: Lower bound = %d, Upper bound = %d\n", i, last_line) ;
        for(x = 0 ; x < last_line + 1 ; x++)
        {
            printf("Array[%d]: %s \n", x, array[x]) ;
        }
        quicksort(array, i, last_line) ;
    }

    x = 0 ;
    return ;
}
```

Comment: The second `lines[i] = malloc(BUFSIZ) ;` was done *after* you incremented `i++` but *before* you check the limit `i < linenumber`.

Comment: You are sorting an array of pointers.  It is silly to perform swaps by swapping what they point to, instead of swapping the pointers themselves.

Comment: Your program sorts your test input correctly for me, and the debug output shows no evidence of the out-of-bounds access problem you described.  The program *is* buggy, as I can demonstrate with a larger input list, but I don't see any reason to believe your claim that the code you presented exhibits the error you described.

Comment: I am running on OS X and can assure you that I get an Abort trap 6 error. Can I ask what happens when you use a larger dataset?

Comment: @James I tried the code with Ubuntu and I don't get error. To me the code seems correct.

Comment: @John Bollinger, thanks for your comment and help. I am using the gcc compiler on OS X. Which compiler are you using? I assume you are not using any special options?

Comment: @Programmer400, thanks for your comment and help. I am using the gcc compiler on OS X. Which compiler are you using? I assume you are not using any special options?

Comment: I just tried this on my raspberry pi and it does indeed work. i wonder why it doesn't on my Mac? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I now also notice errors in the sort for a longer list. Can i ask for some suggestions for improvement to make it less buggy?

Comment: @James I used Ubuntu and gcc, all standard. I can try with OpenBSD 5.9 but your code should work. Can you post more details?

Comment: @James, I tested the code and data you presented in the question with GCC 4.4 on CentOS 6.  I reiterate that not only did the program not crash, the output from all the print statements did not show any evidence of the indexing problem you described.  I find the latter much more indicative than the former, to the extent that I'm inclined to guess that that aspect your problem is associated with different code than what you presented.

Comment: Having copied and pasted the code form the question I still receive an Abort trap 6 runtime error. I compile it on my mac with gcc. The following a print out from the code leading the error after the first recursive call                      `SWAPPING
Array[0] = Dave
, Array[0] = Dave
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: Note: "alphabetical" is usually a natural language concept while "lexicographic" is a more artificial, formal character set-based concept. You might consider `strcoll` rather than `strcmp`. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087062/what-is-the-difference-between-strcmp-and-strcoll). (IMO, string exercises end up teaching the wrong lesson about characters yet they aren't fundamentally about text to begin with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already covered in comments, I see nothing in your code that would explain the out-of-bounds indexing problem you claimed to observe, and I do not observe it myself with your code and data.  In fact the code you presented does not appear to afford a possibility of the behavior you describe.  If in fact you do observe such a problem, then I'm inclined to guess that it is associated with some difference between the code you are actually using and the code you presented.

On the other hand, and as I also first mentioned in comments, your code is buggy.  It is relatively easy to construct a longer input which it will sort incorrectly (I did this on my first try, without any special consideration of your implementation details).  The problem I see there is that during partitioning you use `array[pivot]` to refer to the pivot element, thereby assuming that the pivot element remains at its initial position.  That assumption *will* be violated for some partitions of some inputs, with the likely result that the array is not correctly sorted.

Note also that I strongly suggest that you perform swaps directly on the elements of your array (which are pointers) instead of by swapping the contents of the `char` arrays to which the pointers point.  Not only will that be far more efficient, but it will make it easier to address the problem with your pivot element.  It would in fact be the only alternative if you could not rely on the pointers to all point to allocations of the same size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The code below features the suggestions given in the answer and comments above. This code seems to work correctly, although it is still unclear why the Abort trap 6 run time error was received initially.

Final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void quicksort(char **array, int first_line, int last_line) ;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0 ;
    int j = 0 ;
    int line_count = 0 ;
    int line_number = 20 ;
    char *lines[100] ;
    FILE *foutptr ;
    FILE *finptr ;

    finptr = fopen("names.txt", "r") ;
    if(finptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: input file pointer") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    foutptr = fopen("sorted.txt", "w") ;
    if(foutptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: output file pointer") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    lines[i] = malloc(BUFSIZ) ;
    while(fgets(lines[i],BUFSIZ,finptr) && i < line_number)
    {
        printf("Element %d is the name %s.\n", i, lines[i]) ;
        i++ ;
        lines[i] = malloc(BUFSIZ) ;
    }

    printf("TEST %s.\n", *(lines+1)) ;
    line_count = i ;
    i = 0 ;
    char **all_lines = lines ;

    quicksort(all_lines, 0, line_count-1) ;

    for(j = 0 ; j < line_count ; j++)
    {
        fprintf(foutptr, "%s", lines[j]) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}

void quicksort(char **array, int first_line, int last_line)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, x = 0i, p = (first_line + last_line)/2 ;
    printf("%s \n", array[p]) ;
    char pivot[BUFSIZ] ;
    char *temp_ptr ;

    strcpy(pivot,array[p]) ;

    i = first_line ;
    j = last_line ;

    if(last_line - first_line < 1)
    {
        return ;
    }

    printf("first_line = %d so i = %d. last line = %d so  j = %d. The pivot is array[%d] \n", first_line, i, last_line, j, p) ;

    while(i <= j)
    {
        /* While array[i] proceeds the pivot alphabetically and is less than array[j] move through the array. This deals with first
mismatching letter of first string is less than the second in ASCII character numbers i.e. if earlier in the alphabet as ASCII
chartcters earlier in the alphabet have a lower numerical id */
        while(strcmp(array[i], pivot) < 0 && i < last_line)
        {
            printf("No swapping In while 1, comparing %s and %s with strcmp = %d. \n", array[i], pivot, strcmp(array[i], pivot)) ;
            printf("%d. \n", i) ;
            i++ ;
        }

        /* While array[j] follows the pivot alphabetically and is
greater than array[i] move through the array. This deals with the
first mismatching letter of first string compared to the second
            is greater in number id i.e. the ASCII character code is
bigger in the first so it is  latter in the alphabet */
        while(strcmp(array[j], pivot) > 0 && j > first_line)
        {
            printf("No swapping In while 2, comparing %s and %s with strcmp = %d. \n", array[j], pivot, strcmp(array[j], pivot)) ;
            printf("%d. \n", j) ;
            j-- ;
        }

                // Swap if the conditions above are not met
        if(i <= j)
        {
            printf("%s\n","SWAPPING") ;
            printf("Array[%d] = %s, Array[%d] = %s", i, array[i], j,array[j]) ;
            temp_ptr = array[i] ; //Here we copy pointers which is eaier to do than copy the array contents and is more efficent.
            array[i] = array[j] ;
            array[j] = temp_ptr ;
            //strcpy(temp,array[i]) ; // This is much less efficent as it copies the contents of the aray not the pointers.
            //strcpy(array[i], array[j]) ;
            //strcpy(array[j],temp) ;
            printf("Array[%d] = %s, Array[%d] = %s", i, array[i], j,array[j]) ;
            i++ ;
            j-- ;
        }
    }

    if(first_line < j)
    {
        printf("Recursive call 1: Lower bound = %d, Upper bound = %d\n", first_line, j) ;
        for(x = 0 ; x < last_line + 1 ; x++)
        {
            printf("Array[%d]: %s \n", x, array[x]) ;
        }
        quicksort(array, first_line, j) ;
    }

    x = 0 ;

    if(i < last_line)
    {
        printf("Recursive call 2: Lower bound = %d, Upper bound = %d\n", i, last_line) ;
        for(x = 0 ; x < last_line + 1 ; x++)
        {
            printf("Array[%d]: %s \n", x, array[x]) ;
        }
        quicksort(array, i, last_line) ;
    }

    x = 0 ;
    return ;
}
```