# Why the function wsetlocale() is needed for unicode encoding?

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, setlocale

I learned that Unicode can distinguish many characters used for other languages such as Chinese. Then if we decide the encoding, Utf-16 for example, setting locale is not needed I think. But actually it is not. _wsetlocale() is needed even for Unicode. I wonder why.

```
_wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"korean"); 
wchar_t a = L'개';
wcout << a << endl;
```

Like this. I set Character Set not MBCS but Unicode. Why I have to set locale for unicode?

Comment: `wchar_t` can't store all Unicode characters, it doesn't have enough bits to do so

Comment: @JVApen That depends on the system. Some `wchar_t`s are 32 bits. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) where it says, _large enough to represent any supported character code point (32 bits on systems that support Unicode. A notable exception is Windows, where wchar_t is 16 bits and holds UTF-16 code units)_.

Answer (score 1):

Primary reason is for doing case insensitive string comparisons with such library functions as [wcscasecmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wcscasecmp).  Additionally, some strings may be evaluated differently with the [strcoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcoll) and wcscoll library functions than with the traditional strcmp and wcscmp functions.  More details at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087140/104458).

For more details on how the locale influences the c and c++ runtime, consult the man page for [setlocale](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale).

Comment: Yes. One notable case is the letter `i`, where the uppercase version is `I` in some locales, but `İ` in others.

Comment: @MrLister You mean the Unicode don't distinguish I and İ?

Comment: @Mona04 No, I don't mean that. They are two different letters. My comment was meant as an example to selbie's answer. To a case insensitive comparison, `i` and `İ` are equal in some locales, but not in others. `I` and `İ` are not equal.